# What are the disadvantages of using .vbs files for functions in QTP?

Tags: vbscript, qtp

I'm trying to avoid the work of adding an association to all of my tests by using a VBS file for some functions instead of a QFL and using ExecuteFile to call it.

If I were to do this, would there be any gotchas, besides the inability to have breakpoints in the VBS file? [Source](http://www.quicklearnqtp.com/2010/06/vbs-in-qtp.html)

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While development of you scripts, I see some disadvantages; It will make creating scripts more difficult:

- Your functions are not displayed in the Expert view > Keyword overview
- The crippled intellisense won't work when you enter a certain function in the main action
- You cannot right click on a function and select the 'jump to function' in the main action

And debugging is more difficult:

- (As you mentioned) no breakpoints
- No pausing, except in the Action itself
- That means also: No 'Add watch', seeing the scoped variables during runtime, using the direct output or using the GUI spy.

If you don't need all that functionality, say you have build an unattended nighttime script and now you want to export an action without all resources associated, I'd say there are no disadvantages.
Nevertheless, I would strongly recommend the association method during the *development* of your scripts.

Answer (score 2):

If you load the library with `LoadFunctionLibrary` (QTP 11+), the debugging challenges noted by  @AutomatedChaos are alleviated. The only caveat is that `LoadFunctionLibrary` cannot support user defined classes. Otherwise, it carries all of the benefits of `ExecuteFile` without the debugging nightmares.